# How to display adjusted PIL images in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to make a simple Tkinter app that displays an image on screen, and that reduces the brightness of the image when you click:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageEnhance

def update_image(img):
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
    temp_img = enhancer.enhance(0.5)
    temp_tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(temp_img)
    panel.configure(image=temp_tkimg)

root = Tk()

img   = Image.open('img.png')
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)

panel = ttk.Label(root, image=tkimg)

panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

panel.bind('<1>', lambda e: update_image(img))

root.mainloop()
```

This correctly displays the initial image, but after clicking, instead of rendering the new image it just disappears. I've tried saving the `temp_tkimg` as a new png and reopening it the same way I do with the initial image but this doesn't work either:

```
def update_image(img):
    enhancer = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
    temp_img = enhancer.enhance(0.5)
    temp_img.save('temp.png')
    temp_tkimg = PhotoImage(file='temp.png')
    panel.configure(image=temp_tkimg)
```

I feel like this is a pretty simple concept so not sure what I'm missing.

Cheers.

Comment: Add `panel.tk_img = temp_tkimg` at the end of the function

Comment: @TheLizzard that `panel.tk_img = temp_tkimg` did it thanks, I'm having a read through of the answer you linked now.

Comment: I think I understand, that because `temp_tkimg` is instantiated inside the function it gets binned once the function ends. I'm still not 100% sure why `panel.configure(...)` doesn't work on it's own though.

Comment: Call it a bug. `panel.configure` doesn't keep a reference to the image so yes the image gets binned after the function ends.

Comment: there is bug in PhotoImage - see `Note` at the end of page [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)